# RRDTool give me a blank graph

Tags: graph, rrdtool, rrd

I have been trying to get this to work via trial and error and research

```
rrdtool create attempt_db.rrd --start  1435125034 --step=10 DS:attempts:GAUGE:600:0:1000 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:24

rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd  <time unixtime>:<number>

rrdtool graph latency.png -a PNG -w 7850 -h 240 --slope-mode -u 2000
--vertical-label "attempts" DEF:attempts=attempt_db.rrd:attempts:MAX LINE1:attempts
```

Data sample:

```
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170017.8874:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170248.3469:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170307.1935:2
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170323.2595:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170391.3133:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170396.5190:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170433.3954:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170433.3983:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170446.6604:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170447.1263:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170450.4443:1
rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd 1495170479.7533:1
```

The 1's,2's, and etc have to be summed to get the hourly rate.  They indicate the number of events that occurred at precisely that time.

I have a mysql database of 700k records.  The average flow is 35 per hour.
I would like to have the incidents per hour totaled as a single data point and graphed. There is on occasion multiple events per second so the  has to be totaled.

I would also like to be able to graph each month as a separate line and color on the graph.

despite hundreds of tries, all I get is a blank graph.

updates:

```
rrdtool create attempt_db.rrd --step=60  --start   1435727683 DS:attempts:ABSOLUTE:600:0:1000     RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1440 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:60:2000

rrdtool graph latency.png -a PNG -w 7850 -h 240 --slope-mode -u 200 --vertical-label "attempts" DEF:attempts=attempt_db.rrd:attempts:MAX LINE1:attempts
```

Inserting data:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword db -e "select concat(oob_time_sec,\":\",count(*)) from ulog2 where oob_time_sec between unix_timestamp(\"2015-07-01 00:00:00\") and unix_timestamp(\"2015-07-14 23:59:59\") group by oob_time_sec  order by oob_time_sec  " |xargs -n1  rrdtool update attempt_db.rrd
```

Here is access to 2 weeks worth of data.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByhxkwJBdusDUnBMTFI4bFlFTFE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

First, your RRD Create is definitely wrong.  It seems you are not keeping the data long enough, and do not have any summary RRA defined.

Secondly, you have not told us the data samples so we cannot verify they are within the correct bounds. (update: now I have the data samples)

Thirdly, your graph command does not specify a time window and so is not displaying the time window containing your data.  You also do not have a colour specified on your LINE directive so the line is not being drawn anyway.

Finally, from the late update supplying actual data, I see that the sample interval is often larger than the heartbeat, so the data are rejected.  You will need to increase the heartbeat (the 600 in the DS definition) and probably also increase the XFF setting in the later RRA definition (the 0.5 should probably go up to 0.9)

So, the RRD definition.  Your definition specifies a 10s step, with a 600s heartbeat on the data.  Then, you have a single RRA defined, with a 1cdp=1pdp setting and only 24 rows -- meaning it is only 4 minutes long.  Yes, you are throwing away all the data after 4 minutes, so will never get enough to make an hour rollup.

> *Notes:*
>
> - cdp == consolodated data point.  A row in the RRA.
> - pdp == primary data point.  A time-normalised sample from the DS
> - DS == data source, the actual sample
> - RRA == round robin archive; where the normalised, consolodated data are stored
> - XFF == What fraction of data can be unknown before the CDP becomes unknown
> - Heartbeat == how long between samples before the sample becomes unknown

Since you say you have 35 samples per hour (on average) this means they are approximately every 2 minutes.  So, a step of 10s is far too small, and 1min should be fine.  A 10min heartbeat is likely too big - 5min should be OK - but lets stick with 10min for now as you don't specify how irregular your data samples are timed.

Then, you want to summarise hourly, so you'll need an additional 1cdp=60pdp RRA with enough rows for a graph -- lets say 200, which will cover a week, but you may want more.  This is because 1pdp=1step=1minute, so we need 60pdp to make an hour for the cdp.

So, try this:

`rrdtool create attempt_db.rrd --step=60 DS:attempts:GAUGE:600:0:1000 \
    RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1440 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:60:200`

This sets up 2 RRAs - the first is a 1day long RRA keeping the values at the 1min precision; the second is a week long, rolling up to hourly averages.  We have a 10min heartbeat, so as long as your data arrive at least this often, you'll not get any gaps.

The next thing to remember is that your data need to be added to the RRD in increasing time order, and you will need to have at least 62 minutes of sequential samples entered before you see anything in the hourly-summary RRA.

To display the line, use `LINE1:attempts#ff0000:Attempts` to get a nice red line and a legend.

Take care of all of these, and you should start to see some graphs appear -- provided you use `--start` and `--end` on your graph command to specify the same time window that contains your data!

Now, to get different months on the same graph is a bit more complex.  First of all, you'll need to greatly extend the size of your second RRA -- from 200 (about a week) to 4500 (about 6 months).  Next, you'll need to use a time offset when calling your 'RRD Graph' function to define the multiple lines with a -n*28*24*3600 seconds time offset (I recommend using a multiple of weeks rather than calendar months for a better comparison, but you can use whatever you want).  You'll do this using an extra `DEF` with the `:start` and `:end` options. Then plot them on the graph as separate lines.  For more info, see the [RRDTool manual](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph_data.en.html).

So, as a final summary, basing things off of your original commands:

```
rrdtool create attempt_db.rrd --step=60  --start   1435727683 \
  DS:attempts:ABSOLUTE:3600:0:1000     \
  RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1440 RRA:AVERAGE:0.9:60:2000

rrdtool graph latency.png -a PNG -w 7850 -h 240 --slope-mode -u 200 \
  --start 1435727683 --end 1438404606 \
  --vertical-label "attempts" \
  DEF:attemptrate=attempt_db.rrd:attempts:MAX \
  "CDEF:attempts=attemptrate,STEPWIDTH,*" LINE1:attempts#ff0000:Attempts
```

Comment: I did that,and feed it several thousand records, and my graph is still blank. I added the data samples you wanted.  To allow the earlier records to be entered **--start  1435125030** is necessary also.

Comment: You are priming the RRD with a date of approximately Jun 2015... then you are entering data from 19 May 2017.   OK, fair enough, though you cannot use decimal time in the updates, you must use an integer.    However your graph command does not specify a --start or --end and so by default it will use `--end=now` and `--start='end-1day'`.  Of course there will be no data in this time window.  Try using `--start=1495170017 --end='start+1day'` and then your graph time window should correspond to your data time window.

Comment: Oh, you also now say that you want to have the samples *SUMMED* to get the hourly rate rather than averaged.  This is a whole different thing as RRDTool works with rates per second.  Instead of using a Gauge type, you should use ABSOLUTE, and when displaying, multiply the stored value by the STEPWIDTH before displaying.

Comment: I updated the start time to 1435727683 or 2015-07-01 00:14:43, and I changed the data set to match. Consolidated the values into whole seconds. No change.  Will update my statements above.

Comment: ERROR: invalid option -- 'end=start+1day'  Also invalid --end=1438318800 or --end 1438318800.  Ok the options work with the graph command,but it is still blank.

Comment: I have added 2 weeks worth of sample data.  Please use it to give me a command line to generate even one working graph, and post the commands used so I can tinker with them.

Comment: OK, having seen your actual data, I notice that (unlike your initial example) there are some BIG gaps.  The sample times are regularly 1000 seconds apart or more.  However your RRD is configured with a 600s heartbeat which means the samples will become invalid.

Comment: Using an `rrdtool dump` I can see that some CDP are being set, where the sample interval is <600s, but many are not because the interval is too large.  Increase your heartbeat from 600 (in the rrdtool create) to get more of them valid.  You probably also want to decrease the XFF in the seconds RRA definition from 0.5 to 0.1 or less.

Comment: Finally, your graph command is not specifying a colour so the line is drawn invisibly.  You also need to multiple by STEPWIDTH.  Use this and you get a line: `rrdtool graph latency.png -a PNG -w 700 -h 240 --slope-mode -u 200   --start 1435727683 --end 1438404606   --vertical-label "attempts"   DEF:attemptrate=attempt_db.rrd:attempts:MAX 
  "CDEF:attempts=attemptrate,STEPWIDTH,*" LINE1:attempts#ff0000:Attempts
`

Comment: Ok, at least I got a line.  I change the start/end to graph a weeks data, but only a couple days have a line.  Guess I have to inject more data.